# Poetry: what is the benefit of creating the project virtual environment within your project directory?

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv, python-poetry

[By default, poetry creates the virtual environment outside the project root](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#cache-dir). On mac, for example, it creates it inside `~/Library/Caches/pypoetry`.

However, [I found the following recommendation](https://blog.jayway.com/2019/12/28/pyenv-poetry-saviours-in-the-python-chaos/):

```
# Configure poetry to create virtual environments inside the project's root directory
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
```

Also, [poetry documentation itself points out these two options](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-your-virtual-environment):

> By default, poetry creates a virtual environment in
> {cache-dir}/virtualenvs ({cache-dir}\virtualenvs on Windows). You can
> change the cache-dir value by editing the poetry config. Additionally,
> you can use the virtualenvs.in-project configuration variable to
> create virtual environment within your project directory.

**What are the benefits of creating the project virtual environment within your project directory or outside it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the virtual environment is inside your project, then everything's together. If you delete the project later on, then the virtual environment will be too. If the virtual environment is outside, then you need to remember to delete two directories. However, this is just a recommendation and there's no obligation to follow it.

Comment: it's a good point. if so, I would normally want to ignore it, right? Is there any use case where I would want to keep it across users?

Comment: Poetry keeps virtual environments in the `~/Library/Caches/poetry` so you can delete all virtual environments at once by deleting the `~/Library/Caches/poetry` directory. This might be useful on a production machine/server, but you don't need to do that in a development.

Comment: thanks. And also I not sending to git, right?

Comment: No, virtual environments should not be committed to git.